# Use Regex to select only the second occurance of substring? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

How can I match only the second occurrence of a sub-string using regex in python?

I am trying match and replace only the second occurrence of the string '\n250\n' (250 on it's own line). I want to replace it with 'Chapter 250'.

Multiple occurrences of this sub-string are embedded in a larger string so that it looks like this.

> First there is a large portion of unrelated text such as this.
>
> 250
>
> Then there is more unrelated text as seen here on much much longer.
>
> 250
>
> The unrelated text continues as so but since the capture group begins
> and ends with a newline symbol that is helpful.

I have seen methods to select the first occurrence substring and I have seen much discussion on ways to select the nth occurrence of a sub-string but they were to specific for me to either apply or understand. I'm fairly inexperienced with regex and python so I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary to only use regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

s = """
First there is a large portion of unrelated text such as this.

250

Then there is more unrelated text as seen here on much much longer.

250

The unrelated text continues as so but since the capture group begins and ends with a newline symbol that is helpful.
"""

s = re.sub(r'(\n250\n.*?\n)(250\n)', r'\1Chapter \2', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
First there is a large portion of unrelated text such as this.

250

Then there is more unrelated text as seen here on much much longer.

Chapter 250

The unrelated text continues as so but since the capture group begins and ends with a newline symbol that is helpful.
```

Comment: I'm also in the same boat and would like not to open another thread. If I have a string with 8:00 PM and 8:00: PM, 

I would like to replace only the second 8:00: PM so it becomes just like the first. So the first one would not be touched at all by the regex but the second string would be modified be the regex.

Comment: I solved it in case anyone sees this. 

`some_time = "8:00 PM"
print(re.sub(r"(\d{1,2}:\d{2}):", "\g<1>", some_time ))`

`print("8:00 PM".replace(": PM", " PM").replace(": AM", " AM"))`